# How come the ground shook for days after the bombing raids?

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, the-conjuring-universe, the-nun

In *The Nun* father Anthony Burke encounters a damaged castle and asks Frenchie:

> Father Anthony Burke: A result of the war?
>
> Frenchie: Bombing raids, yes. I've heard stories of how the **ground
>   shook for days after them**.

**Them** refers to the bombing raids

Comment: Nothing in that quote says it continued to shake, in fact I read it as "the ground continued to shake during the bombing raids which went on for days"

Comment: Probably unexploded bombs that exploded in the days after.

Comment: Sounds like simple hyperbole - and not meant as something that literally happened

Comment: In addition to @BCdotWEB comment, the destruction doesn’t stop when the bombing stops - in a built up area you have buildings that collapse due to bomb damage, unexplored ordnance going up, delayed detonation ordnance going up (both sides often used time delay fuses in addition to impact fuses), fires causing building collapse, gas mains etc etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a retelling of stories from those who lived through the raids. People who have been *shook* by them.

It’s typical hyperbole that should tell how extreme the bombings were. To those who experienced them. Like earthquakes they shook the ground and its echoes lasted for days. Bombs of course have an immediate reaction and the resulting blast will dissipate within a moment or two ( I suspect some nuclear bomb shockwaves last longer or rather go further and echo back more powerfully than substantially smaller bombs ) and not perpetuate for days. However the image of it clearly does and did.

The image the character should have should be one of absolute destruction.